# Rails with google maps. TypeError: a is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby on rails application in which in 80% of the pages I am using google maps. So in many of my seperate JS files (in assets/javascripts) I have included many variables from google like

```
google.maps.DirectionsStatus
new google.maps.LatLng(a,b)
new google.maps.Marker
google.maps.event.addListener
```

And I have included the below script in my application.html.erb in head section

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<%= ENV["GOOGLE_MAP"]%>&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>
```

In production in pages in which I am not using google maps an error is displayed on console

```
TypeError: a is null
```

> ...(null,_.ia)},p$=function(a,b){this.j=a;this.ma=a.value;this.Vd(this.ma);this.V=b...

This stops other javascript functions in the pages with no google maps from running.Everything in the localhost works fine btw its only in production (Aws-ec2 server with ubuntu. Server nginx and app server puma) that it is not working. Have I gone wrong with google maps integration? Is there a workaround for this problem?

Note: I am not using turbolinks for the application.

Update: Upon further testing only document.ready functions are not working on such pages. Other js functions on such pages are working fine in production.

Comment: Can you verify in the HTML from the production server that `ENV["GOOGLE_MAP"]` is properly being replaced with your key?

Comment: Yes in the pages in which I am using google maps, are working perfectly fine and the application.yml is being loaded with all the environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Isolate the Google Map API

Remove the Google script include from application.html.erb. If you don't need it on every page, don't load it on every page.

Create a partial _map_handler.html.erb (or whatever). At the top, include your Google Map js:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<%= ENV["GOOGLE_MAP"]%>&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>
```

This partial (or a any number of partials) is where you put all of the map (view) actions. It may not need to be said but all of the google calls have to be only in the partial.

```
google.maps.DirectionsStatus
new google.maps.LatLng(a,b)
new google.maps.Marker
google.maps.event.addListener
```

There are 2 benefits:

- The Google script is not loaded on pages where it isn't needed
- If you switch to another maps api, you'll need to change the partial(s), but you will avoid having Google maps code dependencies strewn throughout your views.

**If you have JavaScript map handlers of your own, you must isolate your map js into its own compiled asset.**

### Three steps

**application.js**

```
Remove //= require_tree .
```

*Implications: You will now have to now manually include each of the js files you need in main asset glob as include lines. This may break your assets but to isolate the maps js, you have to go through this.*

**Important**: Make sure you don't include your my_map_handlers.js in application.js

**assets.rb**

Add a line to compile your my_map_handlers.js into a separate asset file

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( my_map_handlers.js)
```

**_map_handler.html.erb**

Include your my_map_handlers js (will be compiled standalone by the above steps) in the partial after the Google map API and before any references

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<%= ENV["GOOGLE_MAP"]%>&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'my_map_handlers' %>
```

---

Official docs for compiling / referencing a single asset is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for your response.. I tried doing that but getting an error of "google not defined" error on pages with no google maps api script.. as the complete js is bundled in an single application.js asset on the production.On pages in in which I am not including the script the application.js still has google variables(Took me a long time to figure this out).And I am using a ton number of event listeners and map handlers.

Comment: That's the situation I referred on the note at the end. Can be fixed. I will expand my answer to include the asset pipeline component.

Comment: It will take some time to implement this.Will accept the answer after implementation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds fair. Let me know if there are any issues. Good luck!

Comment: Took some time.. but got it working with all the bugs resolved.. thanks.. you da man!

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it. Thanks for for the ups!